# what is com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller mean?

Tags: flutter

I build an app using flutter. I am fetching data from firebase to my build app but some problem occur again and again.

```
 W/DynamiteModule(11085): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller 
 not found.
 I/DynamiteModule(11085): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller:0 and 
 remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller:0
 W/ProviderInstaller(11085): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. 
 Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Comment: hi, did you solve the problem?